# How does one build a mizbeah?

Tags: korban, kodshim

Are there specifications to build a mizbeah?  I understand that stones were used , are there other requirements?

Can one build a mizbeah in our days?

Comment: Why would you want to build one? Why would you think you can or can't?

Comment: I am not saying that I want or will build one,this is a halachic question that you need not vote down because of your own biases.

Comment: What biases? I haven't voted on this as of now though I probably should vote it down for being a poor question for SE. Please [edit] it to improve it by adding in motivation and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there specifications to build a Mizbeah?

Yes, there are specification for building a Mizbeach - and the Rambam has codified them in the first 2 chapters of [הלכות בית הבחירה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L4)

> Can one build a Mizbeah in our days?

The Rambam (ibid 1:3) says that after the temple was built (i.e. nowadays), individuals may no longer have their private temples nor make private sacrifices.

> כֵּיוָן שֶׁנִּבְנָה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם נֶאֶסְרוּ כָּל הַמְּקוֹמוֹת כֻּלָּן לִבְנוֹת בָּהֶן בַּיִת לַה' וּלְהַקְרִיב בָּהֶן קָרְבָּן

That leaves the option of building the Mizbeach on the Temple Mount. Two issues arise.

1. The Rambam says (ibid 1:4) we don't have enough details to build the 3rd Temple.

> וְכֵן בִּנְיָן הֶעָתִיד לְהִבָּנוֹת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא כָּתוּב בִּיחֶזְקֵאל אֵינוֹ מְפֹרָשׁ וּמְבֹאָר

2. The Rambam says (ibid 2:1) that the Mizbeach must be built on its precise location; no deviation allowed.

> הַמִּזְבֵחַ מְקוֹמוֹ מְכֻוָּן בְּיוֹתֵר. וְאֵין מְשַׁנִּין אוֹתוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ לְעוֹלָם

Building it nowadays would require deciding between various opinions as to its location. A job best left to Eliyahu HaNavi, may he arrive speedily in our lifetime.

Comment: Didnt Eliyahu build the famous mizbeach in Haifa after the beit hamikdash was built....in the time of king ahav? that was an individual mizbeach...

Comment: True - but the Gemara in Brachot 63a already teaches us that it was a one-time emergency and by direct command of Hashem. Also see Gemara in Sanhedrin 89b, Yavomot 90b and Yoma 54a that discuss this. the Rambam in משנה תורה - ספר מדע-הלכות יסודי התורה - פרק תשיעי also mentions it.

Answer (score 3):

One can build a mizbeach today on the temple mount even without a temple. 
At one time not that long ago, there was talk of making a korban pesach there.
http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/15755

רבי עקיבא איגר כתב במכתב לחתנו, החתם סופר, כי הוא מציע לבקש משרי ירושלים ליתן רשות להקריב. החתם סופר, בשו"ת יורה דעה סימן רל"ו, משיב לו שהבעיה נעוצה במושל שהוא קפדן גדול ואמר לבל יקרב שם מי שאינו מאמונתם. הרב צבי הירש קלישר, מגדולי תלמידי רבי עקיבא איגר עסק רבות בעניין בספרו 'דרישת ציון', ואף פנה באיגרת לשר מונטיפיורי ולרוטשילד בה ביקש מהם לפנות לסולטן הטורקי כדי להקצות מקום בהר הבית לשם בניית מזבח וחידוש הקרבת קרבן הפסח. גם הרב טיקוצ'ינסקי, בסדרת ספריו 'עיר הקודש והמקדש', דן בבעיות ובפתרונות בנוגע להקרבת קרבנות בזמן הזה. המהרי"ץ חיות כתב: "על כל פנים, חזרתי על כל הצדדים, ולא מצאתי שום דבר החוצץ היום להקריב קרבן פסח, אחר שיבנה היום מזבח, על מקום אשר היה בנוי בראשונה". הבעיה היחידה היא חוסר האישור של הממשלה. כך כותב החזון איש(אהע"ז ס"ב ) "לכן בזמן הזה אי איתיהיב רשות להקריב קרבן פסח - אין לבטל" - אם תינתן רשות להקריב קרבן פסח – אין לבטל.

Comment: Fascinating, unconventional opinion. [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yeshiva.org.il%2Fmidrash%2F15755&edit-text=&act=url) did better with it than usual.

Comment: @cham why only on temple mount? The Tanach gives many examples of mizbeachim built all around the country...

Comment: Alice that was before the temple was built.

Comment: @cham didnt Eliyahu hanivi build a mizbeach after the temple was built?

Comment: @alicefine He did that was considered a 'horoas sho'o' .Not to be repeated.

Comment: @cham what is the source for this opinion that he did a "temporary violation of halacha"... I would rather believe that it is a precedent than a violation....

Comment: Also, Eliyahu made one while the beit hamikdash was still standing so , kal vachomer, when it is not standing I would think it much more acceptable.

Comment: @alicefine  http://dailynach.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Eliyohu-Behar-Hacarmel-By-Shmuli-Sagal.pdf